# Replace JavaScript function with bash script or c++ script on linux

Tags: javascript, c++, bash

Hi everybody,

Is somebody can help me , I need to replace a bugged javascript function by a non bugged JavaScript function in all my javascript files with a bash script (it would be great) or with c/c++ script if it’s not possible, I want to replace these lines of codes on my javascript file:

```
FormGroupDirective.prototype._updateDomValue = function () {

        var _this = this;

        this.directives.forEach(function (dir) {

            var /** @type {?} */ newCtrl = _this.form.get(dir.path);

            if (dir._control !== newCtrl) {

                cleanUpControl(dir._control, dir);



                if (newCtrl && newCtrl instanceof FormControl) {

                    setUpControl(newCtrl, dir);

                    dir._control = newCtrl;

                } else {

                    dir._control = null;

                }

            }

        });

        this.form._updateTreeValidity({ emitEvent: false });

    };
```

With these lines of codes :

```
FormGroupDirective.prototype._updateDomValue = function () {

    var _this = this;

    this.directives.forEach(function (dir) {

        var /** @type {?} */ newCtrl = _this.form.get(dir.path);

        if (dir._control !== newCtrl) {

            cleanUpControl(dir._control, dir);



            if (newCtrl && newCtrl instanceof FormControl) {

                setUpControl(newCtrl, dir);

                dir._control = newCtrl;

            } else {

                dir._control = null;

            }

        }

    });

    this.form._updateTreeValidity({ emitEvent: false });

};
```

Thanks you

Comment: Most IDEs have a *search and replace* function that works project wide. You can use that instead of writing a new program or script.

Comment: Where is the difference in those 2 pieces of code? I can't see it.

Comment: Maybe , i made a bad copy , but one or 2 lines  changed between them.

Comment: Yes, you made a bad copy, the functions are the same. You can just use `diff` and `patch` commands. You can include them in your bash script.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it.
So i wanted to replace :

```
  FormGroupDirective.prototype._updateDomValue = function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.directives.forEach(function (dir) {
            var /** @type {?} */ newCtrl = _this.form.get(dir.path);
            if (dir._control !== newCtrl) {
                cleanUpControl(dir._control, dir);

                if (newCtrl && newCtrl instanceof FormControl) {
                    setUpControl(newCtrl, dir);
                    dir._control = newCtrl;
                } else {
                    dir._control = null;
                }
            }
        });
        this.form._updateTreeValidity({ emitEvent: false });
    };
```

by

```
 FormGroupDirective.prototype._updateDomValue = function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.directives.forEach(function (dir) {
            var newCtrl = _this.form.get(dir.path);
            if (dir._control !== newCtrl) {
                cleanUpControl(dir._control, dir,_this);

                if (newCtrl && newCtrl instanceof FormControl) {
                    setUpControl(newCtrl, dir,_this);
                    dir._control = newCtrl;
                } else {
                    dir._control = _this;
                }
            }
        });
        this.form._updateTreeValidity({ emitEvent: false });
    };
```

I made a script who replace lines between first word  **FormGroupDirective** and the last word **emitEvent: false**.

My script replace :

- cleanUpControl(dir._control, dir); by cleanUpControl(dir._control, dir,_this);
- setUpControl(newCtrl, dir);  by setUpControl(newCtrl, dir,_this);
- dir._control = null; by  dir._control = _this;

the  follow script command check all js file and do the replace :

```
find . -name '*.js'|xargs  sed -i '/FormGroupDirective/,/emitEvent: false/ {s/cleanUpControl(dir._control, dir);/cleanUpControl(dir._control, dir,_this);/;s/setUpControl(newCtrl, dir);/setUpControl(newCtrl, dir,_this);/; s/dir._control = null;/dir._control = _this;/ }'
```